# Invoke python script using command-prompt terminal

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I'm trying to pass inputs in terminal and run python script using terminal. I'm have use

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='A tutorial of argparse!')
    parser.add_argument('--url', action="store", nargs=1, type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--request", nargs=1, type=str, required=True)
    a = parser.parse_args()
    url = a.url
    request = a.request
```

I'm keep getting error even I have add `(resp.content.decode("utf-8"))`

```
in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Here is my code:

```
for urls in url:
    resp = requests.post(url= urls, headers=Header, json = request)
data = json.loads(resp.content.decode("utf-8"))

with open("output.txt", "a") as o:
      print(data, file=o)
```

I'm invoke my script in terminal using command: `python test1.py --url http://localhost:8080/api/auth --payload "{ 'request':'success','input':[ { 'type':' ', 'content':[ { 'type':' ', 'meta':{ 'sample_type':' ' , deatail':' '} ] } ], 'output':[ { 'type':' ','content':[ { 'type':'', 'meta':{  'sample_type':'',  },  'deatils':' ' } ] }  ] }"`

Comment: Hi @nancy, please provide the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: Are you happy with the values that `argparse` produces, the `a.url` and `a.request`?  Do you realize that with `nargs=1` those values are each a list with one string?  Take that into account.  Or omit the `nargs` parameter to get just a string.

Comment: Be careful when passing heavily quoted material in through the command line.  The shell may do some of its own parsing or substituions.  Loading the json string from a test file might be safer.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably importing `request` in your code.
And you are overwriting it in the line

```
request = a.request
```

unless the two are in different modules, you will keep getting errors trying to invoke request API primitives after that.

Just rename your variable of keep using `a.request`.

Comment: Do I need to change variable name for url = a.url to urls = a.url, and requests = a.request?

Comment: Only `request`. Choose any name that is not already used (as in `import request`).